Maximize this function subject to "too general" conditions?
I'm facing a problem I cannot understand how to solve. I have to find the max of $f(x, y) = 2x + y$ over the set $V = \{(x, y) \in\mathbb{R}^2:\ \sqrt{x} + a\sqrt{y} \leq 2, x\geq 0, y \geq 0\}$ with $a$ a strictly positive parameter.
The request is: for which values of $a$ is the max of $f$ reached at points on the $x-$axis?
I am quite puzzled by this exercise. Well first of all I have no "well definite" $V$ since it's a function of a parameter. Yet I tried with the graphic way, that is drawing the level curves of $f$ which are $y = k - 2x$ hence easy, and some of the $V$ with different $a$. I understood that those are all parabolas branches, hence the set $V$ is the region made by part of the two axes and the given curve for different $a$.

Observing the plot, I cannot state much, since for different values of $a$ there are different curves, and different level curves.
The particular request that the max has to be reached at points of the form $(x, 0)$ distracts me: from a Lagrangian point of view, it would imply the active constraints would be the curve of $V$ and the $x-$ axis. I mean the Lagrangian would read
$$L = 2x + y - \lambda(2-\sqrt{x}-a\sqrt{y}) - \mu x - \rho x$$

The fact is that $\nabla L$ gives, among the other equations, the second one:

$$\nabla_y L = 0 \implies 1 + \frac{a\lambda}{2\sqrt{y}} - \rho = 0$$
But I cannot have $y = 0$ then, as it is requested...
Can you please help me with this?
I tried to check with W. Mathematica and this is what it gives me:
$$ \max_{(x,y) \in V} f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 8 & a > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{4}{a^2} & 0 \leq a \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \infty & \text{else} \end{cases}
$$
if EITHER $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ or $x = 0$ or $ y = 0 $ or $y = 4/a^2$
Absolutely no clue on how it got those...

can I clarify a few terms. In your second paragraph, what is $p$? in the third paragraph, what is $A$?

@SiongThyeGoh Sorry!! Fixed. I meant a and V

Let me do a transformation $X=\sqrt{2x}$, and $Y=\sqrt{y}$,
then we have $X^2=2x$ and $Y^2=y$.
Let me consider an equivalent problem,
$$\max X^2+Y^2$$
subject to $$\frac{X}{\sqrt{2}}+aY\le 2,$$
$$X \ge 0$$
$$Y \ge 0$$
The feasible region is a triangle,  with vertices being defined by $(0,0), (2\sqrt{2}, 0)$ and $(0, \frac{2}a)$
Now, we just have to figure out which of the vertices $(2\sqrt{2}, 0)$ and $(0, \frac{2}a)$ attain the maximum.
For the first point $(2(\sqrt{2})^2=8$.
For the second point we have the objective function $\frac{4}{a^2}$.
Hence the optimal solution is on the $X$-axis when $$8 \ge \frac{4}{a^2}$$
$$a^2\ge \frac12$$
which is equivalent to
$$a \ge \frac1{\sqrt2}$$
